# URL with encoded query parameters in Allure report for Rest-Assured

Tags: freemarker, rest-assured, allure

Allure report shows URL with encoded query parameters for Rest-Assured

I'm using Allure-Rest-Assured to attach request info to Allure report. I've tried to decode `${data.url}` value in `http-request.ftl` that formats the final attachment in this line:

```
<div>
    <pre><code><#if data.method??>${data.method}<#else>GET</#if>: <#if data.url??>${data.url}<#else>Unknown</#if></code></pre>
</div>
```

But I'm not sure how to call js or java here.

It's also possible to extend AllureRestAssured.class end decode url there but all the logic should be overridden.

If I disable encoding by `RequestSpecification.urlEncodingEnabled(false)` it brakes the request

```
RestAssured.given()
           .filter(new AllureRestAssured())
           .queryParam("range", "{\"begin\":0,\"end\":1}")
           .when()
           .get("http://localhost:8080/users");
```

I'm getting request URL with encoded query parameters in the report:
`http://localhost:8080/users?range=%7B%22begin%22%3A0%2C%22end%22%3A1%7D`

but I need more readable wariant with decoded query params
`http://localhost:8080/users?range={"begin":0,"end":1}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that `AllureRestAssured` implementation of `io.restassured.filter.Filter` is not yours, but from Allure framework. Since you can't change it I'd recommend creating your custom implementation (basically copy of `AllureRestAssured`), but [here](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-java/blob/8e242a73ae5b4c3a0aa175871613fa63f1f088db/allure-rest-assured/src/main/java/io/qameta/allure/restassured/AllureRestAssured.java#L80) you should add some changes:

```
      String uri = requestSpec.getURI();
      try {
        uri = URLDecoder.decode(uri, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
      } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      final HttpRequestAttachment.Builder requestAttachmentBuilder = create("Request", uri)
                .setMethod(requestSpec.getMethod())
                .setHeaders(toMapConverter(requestSpec.getHeaders()))
                .setCookies(toMapConverter(requestSpec.getCookies()));
```

Comment: Thank you @bhusak I tried this solution and it works, but I guess that by doing so I have to add a license notice to My custom class as I copy `public Response filter(...)` from `AllureRestAssured` and add some logic there

Comment: @MishaGariachiy check this for licensing - https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-java/blob/master/LICENSE